# Laurent expansion - Faster technique

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series, partial-fractions

I'm currently preparing for an exam in complex analysis. There is a type of exercise, where I need to compute `Laurent expansions` about different places. However, my current technique does consume quite a lot of my available time, so **my question** is if anyone knows a **faster technique**.

I will show my technique on an example. Here's the task:

*Compute all **isolated singularities** of the following function and specify their **type**. Also give the **two terms** with the smallest degree of the **Laurent expansion** about those singularities and their **residuum**.*
$$f(z) = \frac{z}{(z - 1)^2(z - 2)}$$

And now to my technique. The function has `singularities` where $(z - 1)^2(z - 2) = 0$, this is at $z_1 = 1$ and $z_2 = 2$. Thus, the singularities are also `isolated`.
$$\lim_{z \to 1} |f(z)| = \frac{1}{\lim_{z \to 1} |(z - 1)^2(z - 2)|} = \infty\\
\lim_{z \to 2} |f(z)| = \frac{2}{\lim_{z \to 2} |(z - 1)^2(z - 2)|} = \infty$$
So, both singularities are `poles`.

For a `Laurent expansion` we would like the function to only consist of addends, so we do a `partial fraction decomposition`.
$$\frac{z}{(z - 1)^2(z - 2)} = \frac{A}{z - 1} + \frac{B}{(z - 1)^2} + \frac{C}{z - 2} \Leftrightarrow\\
z = A(z - 1)(z - 2) + B(z - 2) + C(z - 1)^2 \Leftrightarrow\\
z = Az^2 - 3Az + 2A + Bz - 2B + Cz^2 - 2Cz + C \Leftrightarrow\\
z = z^2(A + C) + z(-3A + B - 2C) + 1(2A - 2B + C)$$
Okay, now we solve the `equation system`.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1  & 0  & 1  &  0\\
-3  & 1  &-2  &  1\\
 2  &-2  & 1  &  0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
 1  & 0  & 1  &  0\\
 0  & 1  & 1  &  1\\
 0  &-2  & 1  &  0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
 1  & 0  & 1  &  0\\
 0  & 1  & 1  &  1\\
 0  & 0  & 1  &  2\\
\end{pmatrix}
\Leftrightarrow\\
\begin{pmatrix}
 1  & 0  & 0  & -2\\
 0  & 1  & 1  &  1\\
 0  & 0  & 1  &  2\\
\end{pmatrix}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
 1  & 0  & 0  & -2\\
 0  & 1  & 0  & -1\\
 0  & 0  & 1  &  2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
With that we follow:
$$f(z) = -\frac{2}{z - 1} - \frac{1}{(z - 1)^2} + \frac{2}{z - 2}$$

Let's first compute the `Laurent expansion` about $z_1 = 1$, we substitute with $w = z - 1 \Leftrightarrow z = w + 1$.
$$f(z) = -w^{-2} - 2w^{-1} + \frac{2}{z - 2}$$

Now we need to adjust the last term in a form like $a_j w^j$. We do so by using the `geometric series`.
$$\frac{2}{z - 2} = \frac{2}{w + 1 - 2} = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{w - 1} = -2 \cdot \frac{1}{1 - w}$$
As we expand about $z_1 = 1$, thus $|w| = |z - 1| < |1|$, the standard geometric series can be used.
$$-2 \cdot \frac{1}{1 - w} = -2 \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty w^n$$

Back to the function, here's the Laurent expansion about $z_1 = 1$.
$$f(z) = -w^{-2} - 2w^{-1} + -2 - 2w - 2w^2 - \ldots$$

The first `two terms` are $-w^{-2}$ and $-2w^{-1}$. The `residue` is the factor of $w^{-1}$, which is $-2$.

Last we would need to expand around $z_2 = 2$ but this works analogously, so I will not write it down here. There I brought $\frac{-2}{z - 1}$ and $\frac{-1}{(z - 1)^2}$ into a form with $w$ and then used the geometric series again. However, the later term is difficult because it's to the power of $2$. But it can be seen as the derivative of a similar geometric series. As we have compact convergence for the geometric series in this case, we can extract the derivative and so on.

Okay, so that was my technique. Very time consuming is the step where I need to compute the `partial fraction decomposition`. And after that, where I need to compute the `exact series` representation of nearly every addend of $f$. And this process repeats for `every singularity`.
I wonder if there are faster ways as I only need the `two terms` with the `smallest degree`.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I've already read that some addends of the `partial fraction decomposition` can easily be computed by the corresponding `residue`. For example in $\frac{A}{z - 1}$, we have $A = \operatorname{res}_1$. And in this case this can be computed quickly using $\operatorname{res}_1 = \frac{g(1)}{h'(1)}$. However, the pole-degree must be known for this approach and computing it may also cost some time.

Comment: You may find the "Heaviside cover-up" helpful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints for faster calculation.

> **Task:** Compute all isolated singularities of the following function and specify their type.
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)^2(z-2)}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> *Answer:* From the representation (1) of $f(z)$ we see it has exactly two isolated singularities. One of them is a pole of second order at $z=1$ and the the other is a *simple* pole at $z=2$.

*Note:* Since you can deduce the isolated singularities directly from $f$ there is effectively nothing to calculate.

> **Task:** Also give the two terms with the smallest degree of the Laurent expansion about those singularities and their residuum.
>
> *Answer:* We start with the partial fraction decomposition
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)^2(z-2)}=\frac{A}{z-1}+\frac{B}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{C}{z-2}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

We can calculate the coefficients of terms with simple poles easily.

> *Answer:* To obtain $C$ we multiply (2) with $z-2$ and put $z=2$ in the remaining expression.
>
> \begin{align*}
> C=\left.f(z)(z-2)\right|_{z=2}=\left.\frac{z}{(z-1)^2}\right|_{z=2}=2
> \end{align*}
>
> Similarly we obtain $B$ by multplication with $(z-1)^2$ and putting $z=1$ in the remaining expression.
>   \begin{align*}
> B=\left.f(z)(z-1)^2\right|_{z=1}=\left.\frac{z}{z-2}\right|_{z=1}=-1
> \end{align*}
>
> Putting $B$ and $C$ in (2) and isolating $A$ we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> A&=[z^0]\left(\frac{z}{(z-1)^2(z-2)}-\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}-\frac{2}{z-2}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^0]\left(-\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}-\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}\right)\\
> &=-1-1\\
> &=-2
> \end{align*}

**Note:** In order to calculate (3) we observe that the LHS is the constant $A$, so the RHS has also to be a constant. Let's consider the *series expansion* of the RHS around $z=0$ and let's check for the constant terms of the series.

The first term $\frac{z}{(z-1)^2(z-2)}$ is $z$ multiplied by the product of two binomial series, so there is no contribution to the constant term of the RHS, since the resulting series starts with $z$ having smallest power $1$.

The second term $[z^0]\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}=1$ since the binomial series starts with $1$ and also the the third term has $[z^0]\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}=1$ since the binomial series start with $1$.

We conclude the contributions to the constant term is
\begin{align*}
A=0-1-1=-2
\end{align*}
as shown in (3).

> *Answer:* We observe  the partial fraction decomposition is
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)^2(z-2)}=-\frac{2}{z-1}-\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{2}{z-2}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

and we are nearly finished. Note that the task is *not* to specifiy the Laurent series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n z^n
\end{align*}

We only need to find the two terms with smallest degree of the Laurent series. But, if you look at the presentation (4) the first two terms *are already* the Laurent expansion of $f$ around $z=1$ while the third part is a Taylor series around $z=1$ and does nothing contribute to $a_{-2}$ or $a_{-1}$.

On the other hand, the third part *is already* the Laurent expansion around $z=2$ while the first two parts are just a Taylor series around $z=2$ and contribute nothing to the principal part. Here are the coefficients of the two terms with smallest degree $a_{-1}=2$ and $a_{0}$.

Therefore we can answer:

> *Answer:* From the partial fraction decomposition (4) we see the two terms with the smallest degree around the poles are
>   \begin{align*}
> &z=1\qquad\rightarrow\qquad a_{-2}=-1,& & a_{-1}=-2\\
> &z=2\qquad\rightarrow\qquad a_{-1}=2,& & a_{0}=\ldots
> \end{align*}

It remains the calculation of $a_0$ when expanding $f$ around $z=2$.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Why do you already know that a part like $\frac{2}{z - 2}$ can not contribute to the series around $1$ and that the first two addends do not contribute to the series around $2$? I mean, I clearly see what the other parts do contribute but why don't we need to modify the other part in order to see exactly what it contributes? I mean, doesn't it contribute to all factors with a degree of $\ge 0$?. Then, for the series around $2$, I think, we should also give $a_0$ as $a_{-2} = 0$. Then we also would need to know what the first two parts contribute, am I right?

Comment: Also, I really like your quick calculation of $A, B$ and $C$. If I'm right, this is compatible with the definition of the corresponding `residue` as, after extraction, the remaining function is holomorphic in the current area. So $C = f(z)(z - 2)|_{z=2} = h(z)|_{z=2} = 2 = \operatorname{res}_{2}$ where $h$ holomorphic in $2$.

Comment: @Zabuza: Regarding $\frac{2}{z-2}$: You can expand it at $z=1$ as Taylor series. Since this expansion has only terms with degree $\geq 0$ it does nothing contribute to the *principal part* with coefficients $a_{-2}$ and $a_{-1}$ which are of interest in this case. And you're right. The coefficient $a_0$ has to be determined when considering the expansion around $z=2$.

Comment: @Zabuza: To your second comment: You're welcome, and I agree with your statement regarding the calculation and $h$ being holomorphic in $2$.

Comment: Is it right that every functions that has no singularities in a given area, like $\frac{2}{z - 2}$ has no in an area around $1$, can be expanded as `Taylor series` which does only contribute to $a_i$ with $i \ge 0$? Thus, if I find two smaller degrees elsewhere, like $a_{-2}$ and $a_{-1}$, I won't need to take a look at any other such *Taylor-only-addend*?

Comment: @Zabuza: As long as the function is sufficiently often differentiable, yes. If a function *admits* a representation as power series around a point $z_0$ and it has only isolated singularities, the disc of convergence is always up to the *nearest* singularity. Within this disc with center $z_0$ and radius $R$ it is holomorphic. You might find the *[following answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725415/expanding-laurent-series/1725741#1725741)* helpful.